# Uploading video to youtube using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, afnetworking

I'm trying to upload a video to YouTube using v3 API using AFNetworking 2.0. The upload itself is working fine and I am able to see a video at my channel. What I'm having a problem is the parameters (the [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource)) to specify the title, description etc which I have to put as my request body (along with the video itself) Here is the code I am using.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Bearer #_token_goes_here#" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"snippet" : @{@"title" : @"random_title",
                                                                   @"description" : @"random_description"}};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mov"]];
[manager POST:@"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status" parameters:parameters  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"video" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/*" error:NULL];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

How do I properly set the JSON parameters for the request?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What is the result you are actually seeing? Is there an error?

Comment: No error. The video uploads fine, and I get a response back. But the title of the video is 'unknown' and the description is empty. I guess there is a proper way to send the video_resource JSON but don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if anyone is interested, the only solution I found for this is to send the second PUT update request to set the proper title and description.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the snippet to the multipart form data

```
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:NULL];
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableHeaders = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mutableHeaders setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"form-data; name=\"%@\"", @"snippet"] forKey:@"Content-Disposition"];
    [mutableHeaders setValue:@"application/json" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:mutableHeaders body:jsonData];

    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"video" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/*" error:NULL];
```

One request, and only need the permissions to upload.